# Flashlight-effect in OpenGL 2D platform-game

Tags: opengl, flashlight

In a 2D platform game, how can I create a flashlight-effect (like in this video at around 0:41 http://www.youtube.com/v/DHbjped9gM8&hl=en_US&start=42) ?

I'm using OpenGL for my lighting.

PS: I've seen effects like this a few times, but I really don't know how to create them. I know that I can create new lightsources with glEnable, but they are always circular shining in a 90° angle onto my stage, so that's quite different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell OpenGL that you want a spot light, and what kind of cone you want. Let's guess that a typical flash-light covers around a 30 degree angle. For that you'd use:

```
glLightf(GL_LIGHTn, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 15.0f);
```

[where `GL_LIGHTn` would be `GL_LIGHT1` for light 1, `GL_LIGHT2` for light 2, and so on]

You'll also need to use `glLightfv` with `GL_LIGHT_DIRECTION` to specify the direction the flashlight is pointing toward. You may also want to use `GL_SPOT_EXPONENT` to specify how the light falls off at the edges of the cone. Oh, you may also want to use one of the `GL_XXX_ATTENUATION`s as well (but a lot of times, that's unnecessary).

If you want to support shadows being cast, that's another, much more complex, subject of its own (probably too much to try to cover in an answer here).

Comment: Please take note that fixed function OpenGL lighting is per-vertex, i.e. will not be evaluated at each fragment of a primitive. Thus for a spotlight effect to work, the geometry must be sufficiently tesselated, i.e. the spot cone must cover quite a few vertices to get an effective spotlight effect. If you don't want to tesselate, implement the spotlight in a fragment shader, to make it per-fragment.

Comment: I don't see much difference using these functions at the moment. Could you please provide a minimal example including sensible values for 2D?

Answer (score 1):

What platform (as in hardware/operating system) are you developing for? Like previous post mentioned, it sounds like you're using fixed function OpenGL, something that is considered "deprecated" today. You might want to look into OpenGL 3.2, and do it with a full shader-based approach. This means handling all the light sources yourself. This will also allow you to create real-time shadows and other nice effects!